# convert dynamic url to seo friendly url in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Cuurent URL is
https://www.website.com/colleges.php?id=NR%20School%20of%20Architecture

we want to change this URL into SEO friendly URL as like,
https://www.website.com/colleges/NR-School-of-Architecture

we used this htaccess,but only the spaces were removed

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# replace all space by hyphen
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

we used this htaccess to remove .php, it worked and .php was removed in the entire site.

But we dint get a seo freindly url like this,
colleges/NR-School-of-Architecture

```html
RewriteBase /
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

kindly help us in achieving seo friendly url using htaccess

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done _any_ research and tried anything at all? A quick Google on "htaccess seo friendly url" gave me multiple hits and tutorials...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any effort of trying to solve the issue themselves.

Comment: yes we tried with some htaccess codes, but it dint work

Comment: Then you need to show us what you've tried and what happened. Like I mentioned in the first comment, there are multiple tutorials about this if you just Google.

Comment: the above htaccess removed only space, but it dint make it as a seo friendly url and also the database dint get connect with it, for that url

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the rewrite rules in a .htaccess file placed in your site document root location after you have confirmed that mod-rewrite is enabled

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home /index.php
```